# How do I update one element in an array and show new version of my array in the tictactoe grid?

Tags: ruby

This is a tictactoe game. When a player chooses a grid via a number, it is supposed to update the picked number with `X` or `O`, and then show the updated grid. Unfortunately, it continues to output the same default grid of numbers. I used `map!` but it does not work. If I switch `@player1 : x` to `x: @player1`, it changes the entire array to `X` or `O`.

Once I figure this out, the `win` method will be the next task to check. Will `win` work to determine the winning combinations?

```
@a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
def game

@game_board = "#{@a[0]}|#{@a[1]}|#{@a[2]}\n" "------\n" "#{@a[3]}|#{@a[4]}|#{@a[5]}\n" "------\n" "#{@a[6]}|#{@a[7]}|#{@a[8]}\n"
@game_board
end

def secondchoice
  if @player1 == "X"
    @player2 = "O"
  elsif @player1 == "O"
      @player2 = "X"  
  else puts "please pick a valid number"
  end

end
def start
  puts " Player One, Pick Your Tic or Toe , X or O"
  @player1 = gets.chomp.upcase
  @player2 = secondchoice  
  puts "Player one is #{@player1}"
  puts "Now Player Two is #{@player2}"
end

def player_turns
  # player 1 gets then player 2 gets until game over == true
  # nine total moves using a loop with a counter will work
  moves = 1
  while moves < 10
    if moves.odd?
    puts @game_board
      puts "its player One's turn! place #{@player1} on the board by picking a number: "
      cell = gets.chomp
       @a.map! {|x|x == cell ? @player1 : x}
      moves += 1
      unless check_win == true
        end
    else
     puts @game_board
        puts "its player Two's turn! place #{@player2} on the board by picking a number: "
      kell = gets.chomp
     @a.map! {|x|x == kell ? @player2 : x}
      moves += 1
      unless check_win == true
        end
    end
  end
end

def win
  # 10 turns(count) with no combination is a draw
  return [[@a[0]+ @a[1] + @a[2]],[@a[3] + @a[4] + @a[5]],[@a[6] + @a[7] + @a[8]],[@a[0]+ @a[3] + @a[6]],[@a[1] + @a[4] + @a[7]],[@a[2] + @a[5]+ @a[8]],[@a[0]+ @a[4] + @a[8]],[@a[2] + @a[4] + @a[6]]]
  #game_over check if player has 3 in a row
end
# Create a loop that gives player turns. Player one then player two until a draw or three in row

def check_win
  win.each do |arr|
      str = arr.join
      if str == "xxx"
        puts "X Wins!"
        return true
      elsif str == "ooo"
        puts "O Wins!"
        return true
      end
    end
    return false
end

while check_win != true
  start
  game
  player_turns
end
```

Comment: you're changing `@a`, but you're printing`@game_board`. What's up with that?

Comment: SergioTulentsev My thought process was, a@ stores the values and @game_board is the actual grid.

Comment: "Actual" grid without up-to-date values? What is actual about it then? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev That is what confusing, I initialized the `@a` array. Why doesn't the `@gameboard` update as well if I change a value in `@a`

Comment: Well, because you update `@a` and not `@gameboard`. These are two different things, not connected in any way.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how are they not connected? I using interpolation within `@gameboard` to display the numbers in the `@a` array

Comment: Yeah, well, bad news, this is not how string interpolation in ruby works. It just copies values, current at the time. It does not then watch them for updates and update the string.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what would be a solution to that then?

Comment: Solution for what problem? The one where you update one thing, but print another?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Problem of updating the string, this is what the question is about. Since I replace each value in a@ with X or O, I will need to also display this progress in the `@gameboard`. Is there a better way to be able to manipulate an array while creating a grid?

Comment: After you changed the array, regenerate the string (run that interpolation code again). As @tadman said, you have quite a number of problems with that code. I suggest deleting all of that and starting over from blank slate, applying lessons learned. After a few tries, you'll get it right.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev nevermind figured it out. I removed `@gameboard` altogether and used and the game works and determines a winner but does not end yet. Not sure where the problems are beside bad design. At this point I just want it to work.

Comment: Here's a thought for you: why do you think you need that rendered string? Why can't you just print the array?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hinting at. :)

Comment: Thanks for holding back the answer I actually appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear why `map!` would factor in here. A simple array manipulation is all that's required:

```
@a[cell.to_i - 1] = @player2
```

Specifying the cells as zero indexed would make this easier.

There's a lot of evidence of going against the grain here that's made for a ton more code than necessary. For example, variables like `@player1` and `@player2` are usually a sign of bad design. Why not `@players = %w[ X O ]`? That alone solves a lot of problems if you apply that array throughout your code instead of having per-player variables. Each turn: `@players.unshift(@players.pop)`

Comment: `@game_board[cell.to_i - 1] = @player2` works but it applies the manipulation to even the | on the grid

Comment: If you manipulated `@a` instead and then rengenerated the board this would probably work. There's a whole tangle of problems here, I'm just trying to provide strategic advice. Changed in the answer.

Comment: how would I regenerate the `@game_board`? You said a lot of problems fell within the player variables. Once I fix the game board I will changed the player variables

Comment: I think you're actually doing it, but the way the code is organized makes it hard to follow. The `game` function should be responsible for regenerating and displaying the board, not just reassigning that variable. That avoids having to do extra work in the `player_turns` function. The general principle here is to give each method a very well defined purpose and avoid doing too many things inside of one, they tend to lose their meaning if you do that. You could, for example, avoid assigning a variable and instead just print the game board directly. That's less code, which is generally better.